# Dpkg Python module?

Tags: python, linux, apt, deb, dpkg

I'm trying to do some package manipulation (a la dpkg) and while I can just `popen` or `subprocess.call` I'd rather do things the python way if possible.

Unfortunately I've been unable to find a python module to do the trick.

I've seen reference to `python-deb` but it appears to be defunct. `python-apt` might seem like a potential solution, but AFAICT it cannot handle individual `.deb` files.

Anyone know of a good dpkg python solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, `python-apt` allows you to work with these files directly. Here's an example:

```
from apt.debfile import DebPackage
from pprint import pprint
pkg = DebPackage('/tmp/wajig_2.7_all.deb')
pprint(pkg.filelist)
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.py
['./',
 'etc/',
 'etc/bash_completion.d/',
 ...
 'usr/bin/',
 'usr/bin/wajig']
```

It's not as complete as I would like sadly, but it has a bunch of functionality.

([more info](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.debfile.html))

Comment: I noticed after digging into gdebi that it uses the functionality you're referring to, and then just does a popen to then run dpkg. Thanks.

Comment: direct link to documentation of `python-apt`: https://apt-team.pages.debian.net/python-apt/library/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Python-apt is probably the canonical way of doing this, but if you require the ability to work on non-debian platforms, I've released an early version of a native reimplementation of some parts of it:

https://github.com/memory/python-dpkg

Answer (score 0):

I have little familiarity with python modules for debs, but I wanted to point out that calling subprocesses isn't the bad thing on *ix, that it is on Windows.  Windows almost seems intended to break calling things as a subprocess and parsing output, but *ix usually makes it quite viable.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Gdebi is python based. If gdebi installed you have access to it's functionality via the GDebi module.

I can't seem to find any documentation, so I'm not sure that it's meant to be a public API, but it might do the trick.